# closure_tree ancestors is giving ancestors in reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tree

I have a rails (4.2.3) app that uses closure_tree on the Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_closure_tree dependent: :destroy
end
```

The closure_tree gem [documentation](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) states that:

> `tag.ancestors` is a ordered scope of `[ parent, grandparent, great grandparent, … ]`.

I have a nested chain of posts (root to leaf) - 'Game', 'Walkthrough', 'Tutorial'

```
> tutorial_post.depth #=> 2
> [tutorial_post.parent.name, tutorial_post.parent.depth] #=> ["Walkthrough", 1]
> [tutorial_post.parent.parent.name, tutorial_post.parent.parent.depth] #=> ["Game", 0]
```

But when I query the ancestors of posts, I get the ancestors in reverse order (root to leaf, as opposed to the expected leaf to root).

```
> tutorial_post.ancestors.map(&:name) #=> ["Game", "Walkthrough"]
```

I am almost certain that I have used the ancestors method in the past, and they do appear in the right order (in this case, the expected result is ["Walkthrough", "Game"]).

Comment: Do u use (or used previously) any additional hierarchy gems, like ancestry or nested set? Did u try to `Post.rebuild!` your tree?

Comment: No other hierarchy gems. I have not tried to rebuild my tree. Will try.

Comment: your data probably got somehow corrupted. Did you have a chance to try `Post.rebuild!` ?

Comment: I did a rebuild, but cannot currently verify it, due to some logistical issues - will verify and update here.

Comment: I'm finding the same problem since upgrading to Rails 4.2.6 from 4.0.4. Reloading the record from the db seems to help, but I haven't got to the bottom of what's happening yet. I think that maybe association ordering is somehow not happening on initial creation of a record, only when it's loaded from the db. That sounds reasonable, but it's weird that it's not been a problem before.